# why the expires_in in access_token use second rather than datetime

Tags: oauth-2.0

Sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to do something with OAuth2. And I found that the paramater 'expires_in' is using second like '5184000' rather than some accurate time like '2017-05-10 22:22:22'.

Why they don't use datetime? Is this because of the time format or the time zone problem?

I have read some docs of oauth/google and check it from stackoverflow but I didn't get what I want.

Can you tell me the advantages and disadvantages about this? Or just tell me how can I get them, please.

Thank you ~

Comment: Good question. I guess it is to avoid client side computation when e.g. the access token is cached or misunderstanding about the time zone.